# Prove using induction that the loop invariant holds

Tags: proof, induction

```
//Precondition: n > 0
//Postcondition: returns the minimum number of decial digits
//               necessary to write out the number n

 int countDigits(int n){
1.    int d = 0;
2.    int val = n;
3.    while(val != 0){
4.        val = val / 10;     // In C++: 5 / 2 === 2
5.        d++;
6.    }
7.    return d;
}
```

Invariant: Just before evaluating the loop guard on line 3, n with its rightmost d digits removed is identical to val. (**Assume** that the number 0 takes 0 digits to write out and is the only number that takes 0 digits to write out).

Prove using induction that the loop invariant holds.

Now I've always thought that proof with induction is assuming that by replacing a variable within an equation with k will be true then I must prove k+1 will also be true. But I'm not really given an equation in this question and just a block of code. Here's my base case:

Just before evaluating the loop guard on line 3, d is equal to 0 and on line 2, val == n, so if n has its rightmost 0 digit removed, it is val. Therefore, the base case holds.

I'm not really sure how to write the inductive step after this since I'm not sure how to prove k+1..

Comment: Note that you do not necessarily have to do induction over one of the variables; have you considered induction over the length of n?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by the length of n ?

Answer (score 1):

The logic is really the same as with an equation, except you replace the `k` value in your equation by the `n` iteration of the loop:

1. base case is that the loop invariant holds before starting the loop;
2. *you have to prove* that if the invariant holds before iteration `N`, it will still hold after execution of iteration `N`.

From 1. and 2. we conclude by induction that the invariant holds at the end of the loop (or at the end of any iteration, in fact).

**EDIT** and this is interesting because the loop ends with `val == 0`. Your invariant (still true at the end of the loop) is *n with its rightmost d digits removed is identical to val*, so `n` with `d` digits removed is identical to 0 at this point, so `d` is correctly the number of digits required to display `n`.